# Fetching of duplicate record

Tags: sql, duplicates, fetching-strategy

I want to fetch  duplicate records from a table (n-1 records out of n records).  How should such a query look?

example (table name = `markslist`):

```
Name         Marks
Janny          9
raj           10
raj           10
raj           10
rose           8
```

If the table structure is like this, I want to fetch  `raj` for two times (n-1) out of 3 (n) times.

I tried using rank, but couldn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, when designing tables, it is best to have a primary key that uniquely identifies each row.  If you had one, this would be simpler.

The easiest answer is to use `row_number()`, an ANSI standard function available in most databases:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from markslist t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```